# Cannot POST child object that includes a foreign key reference to it's parent object via a form

Tags: django, django-forms

See supporting info below. I am trying to create a simple Q&A demo using Django. I am trying to include the parent question pk as a foreign key in the answer posted via my answer_question_form. I am able to pass the question pk via url to my form view (url is /qa/answer/[qid] where qid is the pk of the question being answered), but the view post fails with url not found for "/qa/answer/" I suspect it's because I am somehow not including the question pk in the post request and my view is trying to post to /qa/answer/xxx?

**models.py**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

**views.py**

```
def answer_question(request, qid):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
         form = AnswerForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/qa/')
    else:
        form = AnswerForm(initial={'question': qid}) # Pass parent question id

    return render(request, 'qa/answer_question_form.html', {'form': form,})
```

**forms.py**

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Answer
    fields = ['question','answer']
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$',               views.index,           name='index'),
url(r'^answers/(\d+)/$', views.answers,         name='answers'),
url(r'^ask/$',           views.ask_question,    name='ask'),
url(r'^answer/(\d+)/$',  views.answer_question, name='answer'),
```

**form template**

```
<form action="/qa/answer/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Post your Question" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does the form HTML look like and to what URL does it post?

Comment: Added. I see that I am referencing an invalid url in the form action. I guess I need to reference my question id here somehow?

Comment: Yes, you need to post to the desired URL and also specify the correct id.

Comment: Thanks. I think you helped me figure it out. I tweaked my view to pass the question to the template and then updated the form action url to include that variable. Problem solved. Much appreciated.